# Linear independence of a set with absolute values

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector space $V$ of all continues functions on $R$ over the field $R$.

Let $S= \{ \vert x \vert, \vert x-1 \vert, \vert x-2 \vert \}$.

Is the set linearly dependent or independent and span the vector space?

$|x|$ is either $x$ or $-x$  i.e. dependent implying that the whole set is dependent.
But I'm not sure about it.

Comment: What is the underlying vector space here?  Over what field is it defined?

Comment: What Vector Space are we dealing with? What is the underlying field? How is the operation defined on the Space?

Answer (score 2):

Can we achieve $|x|=a|x-1|+b|x-2|$ ?

If yes, the equality must hold for $x=1,2$, giving

$$b=1,a=2.$$

But then, with $x=0$ we get

$$a+2b=0,$$ a contradiction.